# Java HttpURLConnection - enumerate all 302 redirect hops

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-302

my goal is to use java.net.HttpURLConnection in order to parse all the 302 redirect hops for a given URL.

This is my snippet code (I'm actually using it in Talend SW):

```
String url = row2.url;
java.net.HttpURLConnection con = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) new java.net.URL(url).openConnection();
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
con.connect();
String realURL = con.getHeaderField("Location");

System.out.println(realURL);
```

It works pretty well if there's only one 302 reply.
For instance if I populate row2.ulr= "https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/302.html" the code will output -> https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/Overview.html witch is 100% correct.

My problem is that I'm unable to parse several 302 reply, a typical example is the Facebook URL:
www.facebook.com/ID_account  ->redirect-> www.facebook.com/ACCOUNT_NAME

Using a redirect checker online I found 2 - 302 response (I need the second one):
[image]

This is the CURL output:

```
> >>> http://www.facebook.com/123456789
> 
> > --------------------------------------------
> > 302 Found
> > --------------------------------------------
> 
> Status:   302 Found Code: 302
> Location: https://www.facebook.com/123456789 Vary:    Accept-Encoding
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> X-FB-Debug:   Muf4PfCP9TRKCO17QUf7SV2vsdnrCu6Gw2+sjWAKe0QPGdAToJPcmgH5LHv3NIAhzsJXfPB3a9/mVtuhiiEihA==
> Date: Mon, 16 Oct 2017 16:02:55 GMT Connection:   close
> Content-Length:   0
> 
> 
> 
> 
> >>> https://www.facebook.com/123456789
> 
> > --------------------------------------------
> > 302 Found
> > --------------------------------------------
> 
> Status:   302 Found Code: 302 X-XSS-Protection:   0
> public-key-pins-report-only:  max-age=600;
> pin-sha256="WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18=";
> pin-sha256="k2v657xBsOVe1PQRwOsHsw3bsGT2VzIqz5K+59sNQws=";
> pin-sha256="gMxWOrX4PMQesK9qFNbYBxjBfjUvlkn/vN1n+L9lE5E=";
> pin-sha256="q4PO2G2cbkZhZ82+JgmRUyGMoAeozA+BSXVXQWB8XWQ=";
> report-uri="http://reports.fb.com/hpkp/" Pragma:  no-cache
> Location: https://www.facebook.com/a_name_account/
> Cache-Control:    private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
> X-Frame-Options:  DENY Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000;
> preload X-Content-Type-Options:   nosniff Expires:    Sat, 01 Jan 2000
> 00:00:00 GMT Vary:    Accept-Encoding Content-Type:   text/html;
> charset=UTF-8
> X-FB-Debug:   j2KCBNZ1poIJ0xUeeQYbinpcqq2avoI4z8eWb9Dx/yUUg98uyGYGadydia7en1s5X4DJeaJB7VjxYaRvP+psCw==
> Date: Mon, 16 Oct 2017 16:02:55 GMT Connection:   close
> Content-Length:   0
> 
> 
> 
> 
> >>> https://www.facebook.com/a_name_account/
```

Any suggestion on how to find the second 302 "Location" ->https://www.facebook.com/a_name_account/?

Thanks in advance
Regs
S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be great behavior for a [Recursive Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

You could keep calling your method if you determine that there is still a location in the response header.

```
public void recurseLocation(String url) {

    URL url = new URL(location);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.connect();
    String newLocation = connection.getHeaderField("Location");

    if (newLocation != null) {
        newLocation = recurseLocation(newLocation);
    } else {
        newLocation = location;
    }

    return newLocation;
}
```

Comment: Thx, but is there a way to simply got the index of total 302 without call the function recursively?

Comment: can u pls explain also the line   URL url = new URL(location);? thx

Comment: I believe that you will have to make a request for every redirect.  There isn't a magical way to get all the redirects with only one http request.  We just have to slog through all of them and find the last one...

Comment: `URL url = new URL(location);`  Makes a new URL Object.  Is is no different then what you were doing with the `(java.net.HttpURLConnection) new java.net.URL(url).openConnection();` line.  I just broke out the code a bit more to be more declarative on what is occurring.

Comment: The first 302 is EQUAL to source URL, so if I make another request I'll get exactly the same output.Try to use for instance http:\\www.facebook.com\4 will redirect you to https://www.facebook.com/zuck, with actually 2 - 302 HOP in the same request (not recoursive)

Comment: The first two requests are not the exact same.  The first request is to an http url (note the missing s on http).  The second request goes to https.  The third request is then redirecting to the username.  Often time websites will force using https and therefore do a redirect from http to https for the first request.  Hope that helps.